# Gelpro Mats - do they work?

Tags: equipment

This might not be the right forum for this question, so feel free to remove this question if it is. We have super-hard tile floors in the kitchen, and after an hour or two of cooking my feet are KILLING me. I've been thinking about getting commercial-grade anti-fatigue mats, but they are so ugly.

Does anyone out there have the Gelpro mats, and do they actually do what they say they do? I've had many 'anti-fatigue' mats in the past that have done nothing to ease my aching feet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I find a pair of basic Crocs to be very efficient as kitchen clogs. (As does Mr. Batali, though the orange color may be in questionable taste). They are well cushioned, reasonably priced, and easily cleaned. They won't provide a ton of protection against dropping something heavy, sharp or hot, though they do sell some upscale models that provide more.

If you really want a mat, [these Wellness Mats](http://www.amazon.com/s?ie=UTF8&node=1055398) are superbly cushioned.

Comment: thanks for the great answer...i've been threatened with being disowned if i ever purchase a pair of crocs but maybe its time to suck it up :p

Comment: @dani, I've gotten the same threat from my wife, but after reading Michael's answer I will certainly be buying a pair for my kitchen as well!

Comment: They are a fashion tragedy, but if you sell them as "only for the kitchen", you may get away with it :).

Comment: Shoes will always be more effective than a mat at supporting your body correctly.  I definitely think that clogs of some sort are a better route to go.

Comment: I don't fully understand how Crocs beat out Burkenstocks in the kitchen. Burkenstocks provide fantastic arch support for the foot.

Comment: Birkenstock that is!

Comment: Screw Crocs, shoes designed for restaurant work are more functional and NOT fashion atrocities.  I suggest either Dansko (expensive but phenomenal) or Shoes for Crews (cheap and not as durable, but get the job done).  Both are nonslip, and specifically designed for restaurant staff on their feet 8 hours a day or more, running across hard, slippery surfaces.

Comment: FWIW, I tried Dansko and was marvelously uncomfortable, but that just goes to show you that every body and every foot is different. Bottom line, find what works for you!

Answer (score 4):

In short - gel mats are GREAT! 
My husband has foot problems and I just found my legs were tired when standing in the kitchen for long durations. We ordered one gelpro mat and then found we were sliding it from in front of the sink to in front of the stove (and fighting over it) so we ordered another. Yes, they are expensive, but I would suggest they are well worth it. They eased foot pain, definitely.

Answer (score 2):

They do work. I stand on one at a computer desk all day. I tried it in the kitchen once, but didn't like having it in there. I keep a clean pair of $2 rubber flip flops for working in the kitchen.

Answer (score 2):

If rubber mats didn't work in the past, consider consulting an orthopedic doctor. They may be able to help you with a solution such as arch support.

One [article](http://www.thekitchn.com/thekitchn/kitchen-hardware/gel-kitchen-mats-are-they-worth-it-110527) I found says yes, gel mats are worthwhile. For me, having worked standing up all day in times past, rubber mats worked well for me to reduce fatigue. I actually dreaded lengthy chores in areas that were at stations without such mats.

Answer (score 0):

I have 3 gel pro mats, I spend most of my time in my kitchen. The  mats drive me crazy!! Although they provide relief for legs, knees and feet, they slip and slide on my tile floor.GEL Pros resolution was some rug gripper tape which is a pain. Hard to peel, doesn't work even if I clean my tile with alcohol and they DO somehow get dirt on the back. I am at my wits end tired of the non slip back slipping and having to mop my floor and top and bottom of the darn mats!

Comment: My neighbor uses the rubber shelf liner that looks like it's made from a bunch of bubbles to keep her carpet from moving on her hardwood floors.  (she just has it around the edges for the most part).  It's possible it might work for you, too -- it comes up easily, and can be cleaned.